# Overriding async method (RazorView RenderAsync)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

My code (asp.net 5, mvc 6, rc-1):

```
public class MyView: RazorView
{

    // Constructor passing everything to base class

    public async override Task RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
    {
        context.Writer.WriteLine("");
        context.Writer.WriteLine("<!-- View: {0} -->", Path);

        await base.RenderAsync(context);

        context.Writer.WriteLine("");
        context.Writer.WriteLine("<!-- View: {0} end -->", Path);
    }
}
```

However this override changes somehow execution of overridden method, causing all errors in PartialViews to be executed after response has already started (so developer exception page cannot be executed = 502 bad gateway).

My goal is to decorate all views with comments indicating what file is it, just like angular js does.

Edit:
Code snippet above generally works (all views are decorated with comments) - problem occurs only when exception is thrown.

Comment: Pretty sure that writing to `Writer` is going to start the response. You may need to inject at a higher level to do what you want to do.

Comment: Generally response started means that rendering is finished, it's like saying "started sending response to client".

Comment: Are you using unbuffered output? Classic ASP.NET by default has all contents on hold until EndRequest is done. That way you can totally replace the response.

Comment: @usr
Generally I'm using defaults. I think that problem lies in overriding that method (because it only logs stuff).